# How do I use cudaMemcpyPeer to copy GPU data between GPUs in different processes that cannot use P2P?

Tags: cuda, mpi, gpu, ipc

I want to copy data between two GPUs in different processes using the old API for GPUs that don't support peer-to-peer (they are not on the same PCI root hub). However, I'm having trouble with synchronization. The basic steps as I understand them are:

(Process 0, Device 0):

```
void * d_X;
cudaMalloc(&d_X, size);
// Put something into d_X;
cudaIpcMemHandle_t data;
cudaIpcGetMemHandle(&data, (void *)d_X);
```

-> Send address and size to Process 1 via MPI_Send/MPI_Recv

(Process 1, Device 1):

```
cudaSetDevice(1);
void * d_Y;
cudaMalloc(&d_Y, size);
cudaSetDevice(0); // Need to be on device 0 to copy from device 0

void * d_X;
cudaIpcOpenMemHandle(&d_X, data, cudaIpcMemLazyEnablePeerAccess);
cudaMemcpyPeer(d_Y, 1, d_X, 0, size);
cudaIpcCloseMemHandle(d_X);
```

Is this basically correct? Once I'm sure this is the right approach I need to work out how to synchronize correctly because it's clear I have sync problems (stale memory being copied across, basically).

My GPUs do support UVA but `cudaDeviceCanAccessPeer` returns 0. I'm actually trying to write some code that works for both P2P and this, but this is the bit I'm having trouble with.

Comment: have you studied the cuda simpleIPC sample code?

Comment: Sadly that is for P2P only, and it doesn't copy memory, so there is ambiguity as to whether what I'm doing is correct.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that what you're asking for is possible.

If you read the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1g01050a29fefde385b1042081ada4cde9) for `cudaIPCOpenMemHandle` (which would be necessary in any event to convert a memory handle from another process into a device pointer usable in the local process), the only possible flag is `cudaIpcMemLazyEnablePeerAccess`.  If you run this call with this flag on devices that are not peer capable, it will return an error (according to my testing, and it should be pretty evident anyway).

Therefore there is no way, in process A, to get a usable device pointer for a device allocation in process B, unless the devices are peer capable (or unless it is on the same device as the one being used by process A - which is demonstrated in [the cuda simpleIPC sample code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#simpleipc)).

The "fallback" option would be to copy data from device to host in process B, and use ordinary Linux IPC mechanisms (e.g. mapped memory, as demonstrated in the [simpleIPC sample code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#simpleipc)) to make that host data available in process A.  From there you could copy it to the device in process A if you wish.

Although this seems tedious, it is more-or-less exactly what `cudaMemcpyPeer` does, for two devices in the same process, when P2P is not possible between those two devices.  The [fallback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31632988/1695960) mode is to copy the data through a host staging buffer.

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I'm trying to get - I'm trying to get <code>cudaMemcpyPeer</code> to behave correctly under these conditions. At the moment it keeps on copying stale memory, or possibly overwriting it, due to some syncing issue. The whole point is for me to use the CUDA API to do the staging-through-host-memory bit, if that is the only way possible.

Comment: You won't be able to use `cudaMemcpyPeer` for this.

Comment: Well...it works. I just have a syncing issue. The first time I run it, it copies the data across correctly.

Comment: so, one of the two device pointers you pass to `cudaMemcpyPeer` is obtained from `cudaIPCOpenMemHandle`, correct?  And you're saying you can call that on a mem handle given to you from a process/GPU that is not  in a peer relationship to the process/GPU you are currently in?  I was not able to get that to work with a passing error return code, and it would be interesting to see the code you used for that.

Comment: It works as long as the current device is the source device, which is why you have to `cudaSetDevice` to the source device. If you don't it does indeed error. Does that not work for you?